# Explicit DLL 1 function failing

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing the following code

```
#include "SwiWrapper.h"
#include <windows.h>


HINSTANCE hDLL;


SwiWrapper::SwiWrapper()
{

}


SwiWrapper::~SwiWrapper()
{
}

bool SwiWrapper::Initialize()
{          // Handle to DLL  
    hDLL = LoadLibrary("SWI32.dll");
    return true;
}

void SwiWrapper::CloseDll()
{
    FreeLibrary(hDLL);
}


//WiRawImage* CALLSPEC WiCreateRawImage ARGSPEC((void));
typedef WiRawImage*(*FuncWiCreateRawImage) (void);
WiRawImage * SwiWrapper::WiCreateRawImage()
{
    FuncWiCreateRawImage Exec = (FuncWiCreateRawImage)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "WiCreateRawImage");
    return Exec();
}

//WiCmpImage* CALLSPEC WiCreateCmpImage ARGSPEC((void));
typedef WiCmpImage*(*FuncWiCreateCmpImage) (void);
WiCmpImage * SwiWrapper::WiCreateCmpImage()
{
    FuncWiCreateCmpImage Exec = (FuncWiCreateCmpImage)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "WiCreateCmpImage");
    return Exec();
}

//  WiDecmpOptions* CALLSPEC WiCreateDecmpOptions ARGSPEC((void));
typedef WiDecmpOptions*(*FuncWiCreateDecmpOptions) (void);
WiDecmpOptions * SwiWrapper::WiCreateDecmpOptions()
{
    FuncWiCreateDecmpOptions Exec = (FuncWiCreateDecmpOptions)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "WiCreateDecmpOptions");
    return Exec();
}


//int CALLSPEC WiDecompress ARGSPEC((   WiDecmpOptions    *DecmpOptions,    WiRawImage        *RawImage,    WiCmpImage        *CmpImage ));
typedef int(*WiDecompressFunc) (WiDecmpOptions*, WiRawImage*, WiCmpImage*);
int SwiWrapper::WiDecompress(WiDecmpOptions * DecmpOptions, WiRawImage * RawImage, WiCmpImage * CmpImage)
{
    WiDecompressFunc Exec = (WiDecompressFunc)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "WiDecompress");
    int  result = Exec(DecmpOptions, RawImage, CmpImage);
    return 0;
}
```

And I am using it like this

```
SwiWrapper *wrapper = new SwiWrapper();


if (initialized)
{
    image = wrapper->WiCreateRawImage();
    cmpImage = wrapper->WiCreateCmpImage();
    decmpOpts = wrapper->WiCreateDecmpOptions();

    GetCmpImage(cmpImage, "path\\data.bin");

    SetDecompressionOptions(decmpOpts);

    wrapper->WiDecompress(decmpOpts, image, cmpImage); //This line is failing

    FileImage("path\\data.jpg", image);

    wrapper->CloseDll();
}
```

However when I reach the following line `wrapper->WiDecompress(decmpOpts, image, cmpImage);` it fails and gives the following error

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved
>   across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a
>   function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer
>   declared with a different calling convention.

I think that I am messing up with the parameters but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have the header file to know the input and outputs.

I am not that experienced with C++, well not lately, so my searching didn't get me to an answer that worked although I found a few *Stackoverflow* solutions on the error but I cannot figure out what I need to change

Everything that I have on the swi32.dll is in this rar file in this dropbox link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bfhylzb2evrggp/Lib.rar?dl=0

My full source code is in the following link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jkxfyt6xjeanvng/ConsoleApplication1.rar?dl=0

Comment: the solution is in the error message.

Comment: How is `CALLSPEC` defined inside the DLL? Have you tried making it part of your funciton pointer types?

Comment: The prototype you declared doesn't match the true prototype. We can't say why not because you only told half the story.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what do you mean I only told half of the story.
I have updated my question with everything that I have. (coding && files)

Comment: It is in fact the calling convention that is wrong, it is `__stdcall`.  Declare in the old style as `PASCAL` in the .h file.  The other functions don't generate this diagnostic because they don't take arguments.

Comment: It is only half of the story because this is a binary interop issue. There are two sides to the interop, the consuming side which you showed, and the other side, the DLL, that you did not show.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it is because the DLL is a very old DLL who developed it in thi 90's I didn't find a lot of resources on it so I have to try and figure it out.

Comment: @HansPassant I am going to see if I can find anything on __stdcall

Comment: Side note: Please consider learning [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) it will save you a ton of pain and agony and make your code a lot more exception safe.

Comment: @DonaldJansen [`__stdcall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx)

Comment: Gosh I do not know who to thank but I managed to get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working by changing

this line

`typedef int(*WiDecompressFunc) (WiDecmpOptions*, WiRawImage*, WiCmpImage*);`

to this line

`typedef int(__stdcall *WiDecompressFunc)(WiDecmpOptions * DecmpOptions, WiRawImage * RawImage, WiCmpImage * CmpImage);`

Credits to:

@Mgetz, @HansPassant who pointed out to use `__stdcall` and also the link how to use it

Comment: That only works for some architectures and some platforms. The API apparently defines the preprocessor symbol `CALLSPEC` to use as the calling convention. Use that in place of `__stdcall`, and it will work across all supported architectures and platforms.

Comment: Thanks will try that

Comment: @DonaldJansen I am making a C# wrapper for Swi32.dll and I have all the structures etc in place. Would you be willing to show your code for `GetCmpImage(cmpImage, "path\\data.bin");` and `SetDecompressionOptions(decmpOpts);` Just to get me on the right track? I see your dropbox link for the source code no longer exists.

Comment: @Xtr I will upload my code again to dropbox and share

Answer (score 2):

Because all other function don't take an argument, I suppose that the CALLSPEC that is mentioned in the comment for the Decompress function is different  to the calling convention you use.

Recheck the calling conventions and the definition of your typedef for the Decompress function.